# Is there a shortcut to automatically include a class in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Lastly I've used a lot Java with Eclipse and got used to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> shortcut to automatically add imports.
Now that I'm back on C++ coding with Visual Studio 2010, I'm a bit annoyed not having such shortcut (or I may have missed it).

This must be possible as Intellisense detects the class I want to use and shows me all the possibilities when I declare a new variable, it must know where are the headers needed.

The functionality seems to exist in a Visual Studio plugin: [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/autoUsing.asp).

EDIT:
Regarding to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcprerelease/thread/4830c9e3-c39d-4404-a991-9e5e990cca4f), the feature seems to be missing in VS2010. That was exactly the feature that I was looking for: automatically add the `#include <set>` when somewhere in the code I write `std::set<int> myset;`, or with any custom class.

Comment: Is it really that difficult to know what you are using? There isn't any MSVC support for this and I just checked the VS2011 beta and they aren't adding it

Comment: Well, the thing is that I already checked into the software, didn't find it, tried to google it but didn't found any relevant information, that's why I'm asking, I'm not asking without having searched before ...

Comment: It doesn't really exist at least not the equivalent of Eclipse import organizer. You will probably get a bunch of answers about other nifty features of VS from people who don't know Java quite as well. Which reminds me it's actually Ctrl+Shift+O ;-)

Answer (score 5):

When your caret is on the class name itself you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>   (that's a period)  This will bring up a list of potential import matches.  Select the one you want and press enter.

This only works if the assembly containing the class is referenced in the project itself.

Comment: The smart tag menu doesn't include missing headers for undefined types but this is close.

Answer (score 0):

Context menu key -> resolve -> choose correct class.

Comment: Are you referring to Context Menu -> Final All References -> then in Output window Resolve Results? This uses the VS2010 call hierarchy feature to hide the false references to things of the same name from a different scope or to resolve ambiguity. It doesn't automatically generate include statements for missing header files ...